# `auth-source-search` returns nil for valid queries

Tags: authinfo

In trying to debug auth failures from something that *should* be getting its auth info from `auth-sources`, I noticed an extremely weird thing: `auth-source-search` frequently returns `nil` for valid queries -- queries that in fact work elsewhere in the code.

For instance: I have these two lines in my `.authinfo.gpg`:

```
machine gmail.com login gastove password mypassword port xmpp
machine dev.urbanairship.com login gastove password myotherpassword
```

This:

```
(auth-source-search :host "dev.urbanairship.com")
```

Returns the very normal, expected:

```
((:host "dev.urbanairship.com" :user "gastove" :secret (lambda (&rest --cl-rest--) (apply ... ... ... --cl-rest--))))
```

But this:

```
(auth-source-search :host "gmail.com")
```

Returns the totally imponderable: `nil`. This makes *even less* sense because that line provide auth info to `jabber.el`, *which is working normally*. I've even confirmed `jabber.el` is reading my `.authinfo.gpg` by deleting that line. It's not like it's just the host -- a search for `:user "gastove"`, for instance, only returns the second line, not the first.

So uh. What's going on? Any ideas?

Comment: How about trying:  `(auth-source-search :max 1 :user "gastove" :host "gmail.com" :port "xmpp")`

Comment: _Huh_. That works. It does *not* work if I omit the port. But, also I can query for the otherwise-unqueryable entries if I query only by `:port`.

Comment: I pulled the formatting from the function `tramp-read-passwd` in `tramp.el`, but haven't spent any time dissecting the `auth-source.el` library to see what makes it tick.

Comment: I see that there was a bug fix to `auth-source-ensure-strings` on 12/17/2015:  https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs/commit/938495317a02b06a6c512832d0c6d9530fcd7f2b  That may resolve your issue if you were using a version of Emacs that didn't contain that fix.