# `auth-source-search` cannot deal with multiple consecutive searches

Tags: authinfo

I am a heavy user of https://github.com/yuya373/emacs-slack, and I noticed a weird behavior of `auth-source-search`: If I call this function multiple times, querying the second info always returns `nil`.

This is my slack configuration:

```lisp
(let ((auth1 (car (auth-source-search :host "team1.slack.com")))
      (auth2 (car (auth-source-search :host "team2.slack.com"))))
  (slack-register-team
   :name "Team 1"
   :user "some_email1@example1.com"
   :token (funcall (plist-get auth1 :secret)))
  (slack-register-team
   :name "Team 2"
   :user "some_email2@example2.com"
   :token (funcall (plist-get auth2 :secret)))
```

And the second call to `auth-source-search` fails, making `auth2` `nil`. So, Emacs cannot evaluate the expression `(funcall (plist-get auth2 :secret))` since `(plist-get auth2 :secret)` is `nil`.

I am certain that `auth-source-search` is somehow broken, and have found a prior question to this: [`auth-source-search` returns nil for valid queries](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/auth-source-search-returns-nil-for-valid-queries) . A comment to this question suggested to add `:port` keyword argument to `auth-source-search`, but in this case I cannot because the Slack auth info does not contain any `port` fields.

How can I solve this issue?

Edit: My `.authinfo` looks roughly like this:

```
host team1.slack.com user some_email1@example1.com password ...
machine imap.gmail.com login ... port ... password ...
machine smtp.gmail.com login ... port ... password ...
host team2.slack.com user some_email2@example2.com password ...
```

That is, the entry of `team1.slack.com` comes before that of `team2.slack.com`.

My Emacs is of version 27.1, configured with Spacemacs at the develop branch's latest commit.

Comment: You'll have to show us the contents of your .authinfo in order to determine if this is a bug or not (and tell us which version of Emacs you're using)

Comment: Oops, nice point. Will edit soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yay, solved it: use `machine` instead of `host` for both `authinfo.gpg` and the keyword argument.

Comment: Can you tell us which bit of the auth-source manual led you to using `host` in your `authinfo.gpg` so we can fix it?

Comment: @rpluim The confusion was on my part. Because the keyword argument was `:host`, I incorrectly thought that the matching line of the `authinfo` should also be led by `host`, not `machine`.